# Locale-aware parsing of strings to dates in Windows C++

Tags: c++, windows

I'm working in Windows C++ code:

I'm trying to parse a string returned by 3<sup>rd</sup> party software that represents a date, but I want to make that parsing depend on the locale used. Right now, the date I'm getting back is in the following format: "mm-dd-YYYY tt:ss A", but if I switch the locale to something like Canada, then the string I'm getting back is "dd-mm-YYYY tt:ss A"

As you can see, the month and day are swapped. Is there a way to retrieve the formatting of the date used by the current locale? or even better, is there a way to parse strings as dates differently depending on the user's locale?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <locale>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Region 1: Go from current time to locale-specific date / time.
    std::time_t ct = std::time(nullptr);
    std::tm tm = *std::localtime(&ct);

   // Save the time in a stringstream to be later used as input
    std::stringstream time_str;
    time_str.imbue(std::locale(""));
    time_str << std::put_time(&tm, "%x %X");

   // print the saved stringstream
    std::cout << std::locale("").name().c_str() << ": " << time_str.str() << "\n";

    // Region 2: Parse from a local-specific date and time string to time (Parsing is failing)
    std::tm t = {};
    std::istringstream iss(time_str.str().c_str());
    iss.imbue(std::locale(""));
    iss >> std::get_time(&t, "%x, %X"); // I would expect this to parse my string above correctly.
    if (iss.fail()) {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << std::asctime(&t) << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country
format mm-dd-YYYY is not used by any country. I'd better ask that 3rd party to provide meaningful output.

Comment: I've updated my program now to use the same format that is being used by the user's current locale. I don't understand why I'm getting parse failed, if I'm passing the same string I printed out with std::put_time(&tm, "%x %X");

Answer (score 0):

There is an [`std::get_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) in `<iomanip>`. Depending on what you want, you may be able to use its `%x` conversion to read the standard date format for the locale.

If that doesn't fit your format, you may want to look at the [`time_get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/time_get) facet. This has a `date_order` member function to tell you the preferred ordering for the current locale (mdy, dmy, ymd or ydm). You can then use that to choose the format for your input (if you use `get_time` or `time_get` to do the reading, choose a format string).

Comment: In the example program for get_time, I keep getting a crash on the default call until I change it to this: ss.imbue(std::locale("en-US"));. Then the program just fails with Parsing error. Where can I find what valid locales I can pass>

Comment: @Flethuseo: It's up to the implementation to document what locale names it supports (beyond the "C" locale, which all are required to support, but that's just what happens by default).

Comment: I'm getting a 'Parse Failed' when I'm trying to parse the string using the current locale. It is my understanding that I would use %x and %X to get both the date and time using the locale's formatting for both of these things. I'll edit my post to illustrate my progress on this.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the same format for `put_time()` and `get_time()`

For put_time() you used `"%x %X"`, while for get_time() you used `"%x, %X"`

Hope this helps